Number of states in LALR(1) and LR(0)
Given a grammar, is the number of states of the resulting LR(0) parser always the same as the number of states of the resulting LALR(1) parser.
My reasoning is that when going from LR(1) to LALR(1), we merge states with identical LR(0) kernels, which should bring us back to the number of LR(0) states.
If this is not the case, could you give a small grammar where this proposition does not hold?
